# Cannot get correct results searching a Nullable Column in SQL using EF 6.0.2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, nullable

I am using EF 6.0.2 on a .NET Framework 4.5 project. Using SQL Server 2012

I have a class with a nullable property.

```
public int? InstitutionID { get; set; }
```

My database allows null values so i would like to create a query to check for a nullable field like this:

```
        return _context
            .Users
            .Any(x => x.UserID == userId && !x.InstitutionID.HasValue);
```

Ive tried:

```
  x.InstitutionID == null 
  x.InstitutionID.Equals(null)
```

Ive tried using this false and true

```
Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
```

I need help returning records from the database with null values.

Update: below is my SQL script

I am using _Context.Users.Any() because i want to return a bool value.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
[UserID]        [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[InstitutionID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
([UserID] ASC)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY     =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

GO

**Solved**: I tried it this way and it seem to get me what i need. EF doesnt seem to generate the null value comparison correctly.

```
return _context
        .Users
        .Where(x => x.UserID == userId).ToList()
        .Any(!x.InstitutionID.HasValue);
```

Comment: Is it possible that you meant _context.User.Any(...)? Can you provide the underlying table structure

Comment: If you run `return _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == userId)` do you get back records where `InstitutionID` is null is some cases and not null in others?

Comment: To "return records", you need to use a `Where` query.  `Any` will check if any records in the DB match your query but *will not actually return those records*.  What errors are you getting?

Comment: Yes i meant _context.Users.Any() because i want to return a bool value.

Comment: return _context.Users.Where(x => x.UserID == userId) does return results.

Comment: Does it return both null and non-null InstitutionIDs?

Comment: Yes some values will be null and others will have 1,2,3, etc.